# Filtering value layer according to condition of other layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, filter

I have 2 point layer: layer A have 500 point; layer B have 50 point and these point have coordinate duplicate with some point in layer A. 
I want to find these 50 point out of the 500 points in layer A.

Is there any way to filter ?

I don't see any way to filter this layer based on conditions other layer.

Comment: If the coordinates are identical, use can use Select by Location with intersects predicate to highlight those points that are duplicates.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I got your idea, thanks so much